# openLayers does not work on earlier ios versions

Tags: javascript

I used react 17.0.1 framework to import openlayers map to create a web page. The map doesn't work on ios11 and 12, clicking and swiping doesn't work. The ol version is 6.3.1. May I ask what problem needs to be solved? I still don't understand

I would like to be able to work with older ios versions or do something else

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.